# How can I use the native error icon and error sound in Windows using wxPython?

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

This simple line:

```
wx.MessageBox('Foo', 'Bar', wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
```

Gives me a message box with an error icon and the Windows error noise (this is ***not*** the same noise as `wx.Bell()`). I would like to create a custom error dialog for uncaught exceptions, where the traceback is available in a text control and such, and I would like to include both the Windows error icon and the noise. I know that both differ between versions of Windows, and the error noise can even be customized.

Is there any straight-forward way of using these native Windows resources with wxPython? Bonus question; if the answer is no, what would be the *most* straight-forward way of doing what I'm trying to do?

---

### Results after accepted answer:

I just wanted to show off the results after *Anonymous Coward's* excellent answer, as they far exceeded my expectations. This is the error dialog that now pops up on unhandled exceptions (on Windows 8):

[image: Screenshot]

It also packs the modern Windows "UNNK!" error sound. This is the code behind the dialog. I put it in a separate module that overrides `sys.excepthook` when it's imported:

```
"""This module, when imported, overrides the default unhandled exception hook
with one that displays a fancy wxPython error dialog."""

import sys
import textwrap
import traceback
import winsound

import wx

def custom_excepthook(exception_type, value, tb):
    dialog = ExceptionDialog(exception_type, value, tb)
    dialog.ShowModal()

# Override sys.excepthook
sys.excepthook = custom_excepthook

class ExceptionDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """This class displays an error dialog with details information about the
    input exception, including a traceback."""

    def __init__(self, exception_type, exception, tb):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, -1, title="Unhandled error",
                           style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

        self.SetSize((640, 480))
        self.SetMinSize((420, 200))

        self.exception = (exception_type, exception, tb)
        self.initialize_ui()

        winsound.MessageBeep(winsound.MB_ICONHAND)

    def initialize_ui(self):
        extype, exception, tb = self.exception

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        # Create the top row, containing the error icon and text message.
        top_row_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        error_bitmap = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(
            wx.ART_ERROR, wx.ART_MESSAGE_BOX
        )
        error_bitmap_ctrl = wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1)
        error_bitmap_ctrl.SetBitmap(error_bitmap)

        message_text = textwrap.dedent("""\
            I'm afraid there has been an unhandled error. Please send the
            contents of the text control below to the application's developer.\
        """)
        message_label = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, message_text)

        top_row_sizer.Add(error_bitmap_ctrl, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        top_row_sizer.Add(message_label, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)

        # Create the text control with the error information.
        exception_info_text = textwrap.dedent("""\
            Exception type: {}

            Exception: {}

            Traceback:
            {}\
        """)
        exception_info_text = exception_info_text.format(
            extype, exception, ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
        )

        text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1,
                                style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_DONTWRAP)
        text_ctrl.SetValue(exception_info_text)

        # Create the OK button in the bottom row.
        ok_button = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'OK')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_ok, source=ok_button)
        ok_button.SetFocus()
        ok_button.SetDefault()

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(top_row_sizer)
        # sizer.Add(message_label, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        sizer.Add(text_ctrl, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(ok_button, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def on_ok(self, event):
        self.Destroy()
```

The only improvement I could wish for is for the static text to flow and wrap automatically according to the width of the dialog, but I couldn't be bothered to make a custom control class just for that.

Comment: There's a problem on WinXP with py2.7/wx2.8; the layout is not applied. Fix: remove the panel from the dialog (should not be needed since the panel is basically trying to imitating a dialog) -or- add the panel to yet another dynamic sizer and set that to the dialog. Either WinXP or wx2.8 appears to have a problem with panels and does not properly layout them. You may also want to add the `wx.TE_READONLY` style to the wxTextCtrl and `Center()` the dialog.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward: Thanks for the feedback. It works fine on my system with wxPython 2.9 without using an extra panel, but the wxPython examples and online tutorials often adds them with the comments like "Create a panel so the layout appears correctly on all systems". Have you tried with wxPython 2.9 on XP?

Comment: It to work with wx2.9.4. There seems to be an issue in wx2.8 with wxPanels in a wxDialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `wx.MessageBox` calls the os-specific standard message/alert dialog box (on windows, that's [MessageBox()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from user32.dll). wxWidgets simply translates the flags you provide (like wx.OK and wx.ICON_INFORMATION) to the os-specific flags and options for the native message box.

You can obtain the os-specific icons through the [`wx.ArtProvider`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ArtProvider-class.html).

As far as sounds go, [`wx.Sound`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sound-class.html) can only play sound files. However, if the application does not have to be portable, you can use the [`winsound`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html) module.

```
import wx
import winsound # windows only

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,wx.ID_ANY)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add( wx.StaticBitmap(self,bitmap=wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_INFORMATION)) )
        sizer.Add( wx.StaticBitmap(self,bitmap=wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_QUESTION)) )
        sizer.Add( wx.StaticBitmap(self,bitmap=wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_WARNING)) )
        sizer.Add( wx.StaticBitmap(self,bitmap=wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_ERROR)) )
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()
        winsound.MessageBeep(winsound.MB_ICONASTERISK)
        winsound.PlaySound('SystemHand', winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_ALIAS)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
Frame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: `winsound.MessageBeep(winsound.MB_ICONHAND)` is perfect! Thanks a million.